# Will Lime the future test suite?

Tags: 8, testing

Now that Drupal 8 is going to be based mostly on Symfony, is the TDD / unit testing going to change too?

For Symfony, [Lime](http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/book/1_0/en/15-Unit-and-Functional-Testing) is the preferred testing suite. Is that true for Drupal 8 too?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You linked the Symfony 1 documentation, which shows this warning.

> This version of Symfony is not maintained anymore. If some of your projects still use this version, consider upgrading.

The relevant link is the [Testing](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/testing.html) chapter in the Symfony 2 book. Both Symfony 2 and Drupal 8 is using PHPunit although Drupal 8 didn't throw out the massive amount of functional tests written with our bastardized version of Simpletest. You can [clone](http://drupal.org/project/drupal/git-instructions) Drupal and in the `core` directory just run `phpunit` (if you have installed it already). Alternatively, enable the Testing module and then you can run the PHPunit tests from that UI.

Answer (score 5):

Not sure about Lime, but Drupal 8 is set to use PHPUnit. See [Deploy a PHPUnit system with a bottom-up approach](http://drupal.org/node/1801176).

> ## Deploy a PHPUnit system with a bottom-up approach
>
> ### Issue Summary
>
> Replace the SimpleTest framework with PHPUnit.
>
> ### Problem/Motivations
>
> The [SimpleTest](http://sourceforge.net/projects/simpletest/files/) framework no longer has the same level of maintenance than the [PHP Unit](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/) framework. PHPUnit has become the standard; most frameworks use it (ZF1 & 2, Cake, Symfony2, ...) and is actively maintained, sable and works great for every codebase, scenario.
>
> Replacing the testing framework with PHPUnit will allow better consistency in the drupal 8 codebase, by aligning ourselves with Symfony2 testing tools. Moreover, it integrates better with IDE ([NetBeans](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/phpunit.html), Eclipse, IntelliJ IDEA), Continuous Integration servers such as [Jenkins/Hudson](http://jenkins-php.org/), and with [Sonar](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/PHP+Plugin) for static code analysis as well. It has also code coverage which is a huge +.

**EDIT**

Following the comment from chx below about me posting the wrong issue, I'm pretty sure that this is the issue that noted the progress of PHPUnit: [Start using PHPUnit for unit tests](http://drupal.org/node/1901670)

Comment: Yep, just grepped D8 codebase - no mention of Lime, nor on Google

Comment: Would the downvoter care to explain the problem?  Has the information I posted changed?

Comment: That issue is all talk and no action. Different people (or rather just one: msonnabaum) finally took action in a different issue. Given which issue you linked all you could quote is, again, talk and could not point out that a) PHPUnit is already in and b) how to run it.

Comment: @chx Aah, I apologise! I should have made sure that was the correct issue before posting.  Also, I never meant any offence asking what the problem was - I was genuinely curious :)